# In SnowFlake, I want to provide access kind ofddl_admin in sql server

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In SnowFlake, I want to provide access kind ofddl_admin in sql server to a user or role who can drop any tables in schema regardless anybody else is the owner of the table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of having a super role in Snowflake. Everything has to go by access hierarchy. 
However, if all the roles are granted to ACCOUNTADMIN role then no matter which user creates the table, that can be dropped by ACCOUNTADMIN.